# Add Gridlines using ChartKick in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, chart.js, chartkick

Using [ChartKick](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick) with and [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org) I want to add horizontal gridlines. Data range is 100 to 200..

I'd like to have horizontal grid lines every 10 units.

```
<script src="https://cdnout.com/jquery/"></script>
<script src="https://cdnout.com/Chart.js/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://lib.arvancloud.com/ar/chartkick/2.3.0/chartkick.min.js"></script>

<%
  begin_tracking = Time.zone.parse('2021-03-24 18:33:00-07')
  current_date = Time.now 
%>

<%= line_chart DataTable.where(statdate: begin_tracking..current_date).pluck(:statdate, :data_ordinate), min: 100, max: 200, dataset: {borderWidth: 50} %>
```

I thought `dataset: {borderWidth: 50}` would do just that, but it's having no visible effect.

Docs quote:

```
To customize datasets in Chart.js, use:

<%= line_chart data, dataset: {borderWidth: 10} %>
You can pass this option to individual series as well.
```

Nothing about grid lines in Chart Kick and I wouldn't know how to translate the chart.js to Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full details of all of the options are at  https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html.

The general form is something like this:

```
<%= line_chart chart_path(@obj), 
  code: false,
  points: false, 
  min: 0, 
  max: 20, 
  colors: ["#0284C7", "#44403C"], 
  height: '105px', 
  width: '175px',
  library: { 
    scales: {           
      x: {
       display: false,
      },
      y: {
       display: true,
       font: {
          size: 6,
          weight: 100
      }
    }
  } %>
```

the display attributes indicate whether to show the grid or not.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I appear to be missing something.

My chart

    <div class="text-center font-weight-bold">
      <%= line_chart DataTable.where(statdate: Time.now - 1.month..Time.now).pluck(:statdate, :data), title: "Previous 30 days", ytitle: "Title", min: 100, max: 200",
      library: { 
        scales: {
          x: {
           display: true,
          },
          y: {
           display: true,
           font: {
              size: 25,
              weight: 100
          }
          }}}
      %>
    </div>

and the graph looks the same with or w/o the lib…

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the CDN I found was out of date. With the CDN from [jsDelivr](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartkick@4.1.0/dist/chartkick.min.js%22) the grid lines show up. The time scale formatting is different, but assume fixable. So the answer was right or on the right path. Thank you.